# asp.net manually adding a row from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, insert

How can I manually add row/insert into DB with a gridview control?

I need to perform some calculations on the user input first before sending the data to the INSERT sql query.

There is a `gridview.Insert()` method but it does not take any parameters.

How can I pass it my parameters, which come from textboxes, dropdownlists, etc and then run the sql query?

Comment: Add it to the end(or beginning) of the datatable with dt.Add(...) before binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add it in datatable before binding it:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
// set dr fields here
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: Will that persist in the Database also? Or just in the gridview?

Comment: @sd_dracula Just in the gridview.

Comment: I need to update the DB also. How can I run a sql insert with my custom parameters?

Comment: the way you insert data in DB depends on approach you choose to communicate with it. it can be done using ado.net, linq etc.